# Trying to run computer off DC but monitor is always blank

Tags: power-supply, battery, power

I am trying to get a computer to run off a DC battery. The computer seems to start fine (the CPU fan spins and the hard drive whirs), but nothing displays on the monitor. It just stays blank, as if there is no signal being sent to it.

The computer is fine. When I switch back to the ac power supply, everything functions normally, including the monitor.

I'm using a DC to DC power supply connected to a 12V battery.

I am wondering if the problem is lack of power. The DC to DC power supply is only 160W. Does anyone think upgrading to a 200W power supply might help?

EDIT:

Here's the details of the computer as suggested by comments.

Motherboard : asus p8z77-i
CPU : Intel G2120
RAM : 16GB. 2x 8GB sticks DDR3 1333
HD : 1TB
I also have a keyboard attached via USB.

I used this site to try and calculate what I might need, but I may have gotten some things wrong : http://extreme.outervision.com/PSUEngine

Comment: Any details about the computer hardware ? that will tell us if you have enough power. Without them it can be 50W to 1000W

Comment: sounds like you are simply not giving it enough power.  You sure the hardware you have will support a higher wattage?

Comment: Update : I managed to get a 250Watt dc to dc psu and tried that. There's no change, still a blank monitor.